# modify specific redux-form value from custom function callback in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

I have modified the `onDrop` function of `ImageInput` so that it will eventually return a url from my custom function. However, I would like to set that return value to the `image` value of `ImageInput`.

```
...

const uploadImg = ( acceptedFiles ) => { 
    return Promise.resolve(uploadImageToServer(file))
        .then( url => {
            // do something ...
        })
}

const ProductEdit = ({ classes, ...props }) => (
    <Edit {...props} title={<ProductTitle />}>
        <TabbedForm>
          <FormTab label="resources.categories.tabs.details" path="details">
                <ImageInput source="image" label="Related pictures" accept="image/*" options={{onDrop: uploadImg}}>
                    <ImageField source="image" src="url" title="title" />
                </ImageInput>
          </FormTab>
        </TabbedForm>

...
```

Is this ever possible in a functional component? I have seen in other answers that could call `this.props.change(...)` to dispatch a change to the redux-form. But here my `uploadImg` is a plain function out of react.component's context and therefore unable to access `this`.

Or else would I have to rewrite this component into a class component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution was to create a custom action and dispatch the action with `redux-form`'s `connect` method.

Use `FormDataConsumer` to get the formData and dispatch method.

```js
+ import { FormDataConsumer, REDUX_FORM_NAME } from 'react-admin';
+ import { change } from 'redux-form';
+ import {changeImgUrl} from './actions';

...

const uploadImg = ( params, dispatch ) => {
    result = await Promise.resolve(yourUploadImgFunc(params))
             .then( res => return changeImgUrl(res) )
    dispatch(change(REDUX_FORM_NAME, 'image', result))
}

const ProductEdit = ({ classes, ...props }) => (
    <Edit {...props} title={<ProductTitle />}>
        <TabbedForm>
          <FormTab label="resources.categories.tabs.details" path="details">
             <FormDataConsumer>
               {({ formData, dispatch, ...rest }) => (
                <Fragment>
                  <ImageInput source="image" label="Related pictures" accept="image/*" options={{onDrop: (params) => uploadImg(params, dispatch)}}>
                      <ImageField source="image" src="url" title="title" />
                  </ImageInput>
               )}
                </Fragment>
             </FormDataConsumer>
          </FormTab>
        </TabbedForm>
...
```

Then define a new action:

```js
// actions.js
export const CHANGE_IMG_URL = 'CHANGE_IMG_URL';

export const changeImgUrl = img_url => ({
    type: CHANGE_IMG_URL,
    url: img_url
});
```

Summary:
1. collect redux's `dispatch` props from react-admin's `FormDataConsumer`.
2. use redux-form's `change` method to create the action with your custom action.

Not sure if it's the best way but it surely works. Hope it helps anyone who are trying with customisation on react-admin.